# Does double subfactorial exist?

Tags: soft-question, factorial

Mainly, I have 2 questions regarding factorial. However since I'm only allowed to post one question per one post, I'll post my second question later. The reason I'm asking these questions is because someone posted this problem on Facebook and I'm interested in knowing how to solve this:

[image]

First question is 'does double subfactorial exist?' For instance, I'm wondering how to calculate

$$!!5$$

I found the general formula from [Wolfram Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subfactorial.html) for single-subfactorial i.e.

$$!n \equiv n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$

How about double subfactorial? Is it

$$!!n \equiv n!!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{k!!}\quad?$$

The link I provide above also gives the alternative i.e. generalizing the subfactorial into complex number. I read somewhere that this function ($f(z) = !z$) is analytic and defined in the whole complex z-plane (unlike the gamma function that the domain has no negative integers). Anyway, this is another representation of $!n$:

$$\int_{-1}^{\infty} x^n e^{-(x+1)}\, \Bbb d x$$

In conclusion, how do I compute the double subfactorial of any number by a formula?

Comment: Notice that they give good approximation $!!n\sim k \,n!!$ with a different $k$ for even $n$ or odd $n$. Computed for $n=10^4$, $k_{\text{even}}=0.6065306597126334236037995$ and for $n=10^4+1$, $k_{\text{odd}}=0.7247784590070763318182280$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find a table of double subfactorials in sequence $A334578$ in $OEIS$ (have look [here](https://oeis.org/search?q=double+subfactorial&language=english&go=Search)).

As you will read it in the title, they "simply" are
$$!!n= (-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor }\,n\text{!!}\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\frac{(-1)^i}{(n-2 i)\text{!!}}$$

Still according to the documentation, they obey the reccurence equation
$$a_{n}=n\,a_{n-2}+(-1)^{\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor }\qquad \text{with} \qquad a_0=a_1=1$$

You will find a table fof the first $807$ terms (this is probably because this term is the last before $10^{1000}$).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. I'll try the formula and I'll be back soon to confirm whether it works or not. I'll also accept this answer later after testing the formula, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Wonderful! I've tried your formula on Mathematica and it's work. Thank you.

Comment: @user516076. Good to know and glad to help ! I hope that you took the Mathematica syntax from the documention (it is quite efficient). Cheers :-)

Comment: @user516076. It is not *my formula* !